# Elasticsearch: How to cache boolean query without filter?

Tags: caching, elasticsearch

I have a query like below to search and I want to cache it without using filter.
The code below works well but i could not use "_cache":true with it.

```
{"query": {
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "match": {
        "keywords": "heart"
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "treatment_name": "heart"
      }
    },
    {
      "wildcard": {
        "keywords": "heart*"
      }
    },
    {
      "wildcard": {
        "treatment_name": "heart*"
      }
    },
    {
      "fuzzy": {
        "keywords": "heart"
      }
    },
    {
      "fuzzy": {
        "treatment_name": "heart"
      }
    }
  ],
  "minimum_should_match": 2
}}}
```

The second code works too but the result does not have any score, which is very much required.

```
{"filter": {
"fquery": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "keywords": "heart"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "treatment_name": "heart"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "keywords": "heart*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "treatment_name": "heart*"
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "keywords": "heart"
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "treatment_name": "heart"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  },
  "_cache": true
}}}
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch does not cache queries. The reason is that the score has to be calculated separately for each query. The caching functionality is only provided for filters.